# How to add active element id to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to add the id value of active element into a url. Then using a button to redirect to the url.

HTML

```
<div class="icon" tabindex="0" id="company">
    <img src="company.png">
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">jump</button>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction(){
   var x = document.activeElement.id;
   location.href = "apps-online.html?page=" + x;
}
```

My expectations was: when I click the button, it will redirect to page

"apps-online.html?page=company"

However, the url of the new page is

"apps-online.html?page="

I was wondering why the value of x hasn't been added to the url.

---

Hi, everyone. For now I have understood why this problem happened. Because every time when I click the button, the button became the last active element.

So is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Try take a look at this demo, it shows how it works. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_activeelement

Comment: `document.activeElement` on button click will always be that button.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, I learnt how to get value of active element from this webpage. But the value cannot be added into the url.

Comment: @ZanlaiHu Yes it can. Your example shows that it works! The problem is that you have `activeElement` wrong.

Comment: The button you click will be the active element. you can test it by setting an ID for button element.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Thank you! That's why it can't work. Can you give me a solution to my problem?

Comment: sure, @ZanlaiHu, is it that img or do you have multiple img?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph There are several images in the page.  I wish the customer can choose the img they like, and click the same button but redirect to different page.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the button, the active element is button itself. I am assuming you have several divs and you need to pass the id of the highlighted element. You need to send the id to the function in some way.

Take a look below. This can be one of the many possible solutions.

> HTML

```
<div class="icon" tabindex="0" id="company">
    <img src="company.png">
</div>
<div class="icon" tabindex="1" id="something">
    <img src="something.png">
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">jump</button>
```

> JS

```
let tabID = null;
let icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');

for (icon of icons) 
{
    icon.onclick = function() 
    {
        tabID = document.activeElement.id;
    }
}

function myFunction()
{
    window.open("apps-online.html?page=" + tabID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly my problem is and the result I wish.

Comment: Just confused what the 'tabID' used for?

Comment: @ZanlaiHu  If you don't store tabID, you can't use it. Whenever a div is clicked, it gets updated and finally your button uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Do check the value of x whether it is empty or not if it is empty the value of x will be passed as empty so there is no value in the url .try debugging the code or use console.log

```
function myFunction(){
   var x = document.activeElement.id;
   console.log(x);
   location.href = "apps-online.html?page=" + x;
}
```

this gives the value of x in the console check this.

Comment: The value is not empty. The problem is this function only return the id of the button. Because the button is the last active element.

Answer (score 0):

Your button does not have an id.

Give `id="company"` to button element.

```
<div class="icon" tabindex="0">
  <img src="company.png">
</div>
<button id="company" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">jump</button>
```